# Rstudio crashing right after opening it

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

I have installed RStudio on Mac OSX from this file: RStudio-1.1.419.dmg, found at this address: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download1. However, when I start Rstudio, by double-clicking Rstudio in Applications for example, it aborts immediately and gives the following message: ‘R Session aborted, R encountered a fatal error, the session was terminated’. It gives me the option ‘Start a new session’ but if I click it, the fatal error happens again. I have tried deleting ‘.rstudio-desktop’ from my home to reset the default parameters but this did not improve the situation. I had Rstudio before and I removed it but maybe there is some leftover of my previous installation interfering with this one? Anyone has got some suggestions to help me, please?

The diagnostic report is [here](https://gofile.io/?c=YrPhex#99906).

I posted this question [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-session-aborts-after-opening-it/4514/5) a week ago but I am still without Rstudio. If this is inappropriate, I will delete this question.

Comment: What happens if you start R from the command line?

Comment: It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Try Preview version? https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: Assuming you've already tried reinstalling, to diagnose the problem you need to go see what the error says. It should show up in Console if you search.

Comment: In your diagnostic report, I see R_HOME is "/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.3_1/lib/R".  That sounds like a brew install.  Have you tried installing the R binary from CRAN?

Comment: I have installed it from CRAN [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/). But how can I stop R_HOME pointing to "/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.3_1/lib/R"? What even is this R_HOME? A bash variable?

Comment: Good that you solved it.  To answer your question, R_HOME is an environment variable, usually created by R when it starts (but you can create it before starting R; I don't know if that has any effect).

Comment: When I type 'echo $R_HOME' in my terminal, it returns nothing. How can I check what is in this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to user2554330

rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.3_1/lib/R

Rstudio started working again.